# TensorFlow binary classifier outputs predictions for 3 classes instead of 2?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, classification

When I print out the predictions, the output includes 3 separate classes `0, 1, and 2` but I only give it 2 separate classes in the training set `0 and 1`.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  I'm trying to elaborate on a tutorial from [TensorFlow Machine Learning Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1786462168).  This is based on the last example of Chapter 2 if anyone has access to it.  Note, there are some errors but that may be incompatibility between the older version from the text.

Anyways, I am trying to develop a very rigid structure when building my models so I can get it engrained in muscle memory.  I am instantiating the `tf.Graph` before-hand for each `tf.Session` of a set of computations and also setting the number of threads to use. Note, I am using `TensorFlow 1.0.1` with `Python 3.6.1` so the `f"formatstring{var}"` won't work if you have an older version of Python.

Where I am getting confused is the last step in the prediction under `# Accuracy Predictions` section.  **Why am I getting 3 classes for my classification and why is my accuracy so poor for such a simple classification?** I am fairly new at this type of model-based machine learning so I'm sure it's some syntax error or assumption I have made.  **Is there an error in my code?**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing

# Set number of CPU to use
tf_max_threads = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count())

# Data
seed= 0
size = 50
x = np.concatenate((np.random.RandomState(seed).normal(-1,1,size),
                    np.random.RandomState(seed).normal(2,1,size)
                   )
                  )
y = np.concatenate((np.repeat(0, size), 
                    np.repeat(1, size)
                   )
                  )

# Containers
loss_data = list()
A_data = list()

# Graph
G_6 = tf.Graph()
n = 25

# Containers
loss_data = list()
A_data = list()

# Iterations
n_iter = 5000

# Train / Test Set
tr_ratio = 0.8
tr_idx = np.random.RandomState(seed).choice(x.size, round(tr_ratio*x.size), replace=False)
te_idx = np.array(list(set(range(x.size)) - set(tr_idx)))


# Build Graph
with G_6.as_default():
    # Placeholders
    pH_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1], name="pH_x")
    pH_y_hat = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1], name="pH_y_hat")

    # Train Set
    x_train = x[tr_idx].reshape(-1,1)
    y_train = y[tr_idx].reshape(-1,1)
    # Test Set
    x_test= x[te_idx].reshape(-1,1)
    y_test = y[te_idx].reshape(-1,1)

    # Model
    A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(mean=10, stddev=1, shape=[1], seed=seed), name="A")
    model = tf.multiply(pH_x, A)

    # Loss
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model, labels=pH_y_hat))
    with tf.Session(graph=G_6, config=tf_max_threads) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # Optimizer
        op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.03)
        train_step = op.minimize(loss)
        # Train linear model 
        for i in range(n_iter):
            idx_random = np.random.RandomState(i).choice(x_train.size, size=n)
            x_tr = x[idx_random].reshape(-1,1)
            y_tr = y[idx_random].reshape(-1,1)

            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={pH_x:x_tr, pH_y_hat:y_tr})

            # Iterations
            A_iter = sess.run(A)[0]
            loss_iter = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={pH_x:x_tr, pH_y_hat:y_tr}).mean()
            # Append
            loss_data.append(loss_iter)
            A_data.append(A_iter)

#             Log
            if (i + 1) % 1000 == 0:
                print(f"Step #{i + 1}:\tA = {A_iter}", f"Loss = {to_precision(loss_iter)}", sep="\t")
                print()   

        # Accuracy Predictions
        A_result = sess.run(A)
        y_ = tf.squeeze(tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model, labels=pH_y_hat)))

        correct_predictions = tf.equal(y_, pH_y_hat)
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float32))
        print(sess.run(y_, feed_dict={pH_x:x_train, pH_y_hat:y_train}))
        print("Training:",
              f"Accuracy = {sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={pH_x:x_train, pH_y_hat:y_train})}", 
              f"Shape = {x_train.shape}", sep="\t")

        print("Testing:",
              f"Accuracy = {sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={pH_x:x_test, pH_y_hat:y_test})}", 
              f"Shape = {x_test.shape}", sep="\t")

# Plot path
with plt.style.context("seaborn-whitegrid"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(6,6))
    pd.Series(loss_data,).plot(ax=ax[0], label="loss", legend=True)
    pd.Series(A_data,).plot(ax=ax[1], color="red", label="A", legend=True)
    ax[2].hist(x[:size], np.linspace(-5,5), label="class_0", color="red")
    ax[2].hist(x[size:], np.linspace(-5,5), label="class_1", color="blue")

    alphas = np.linspace(0,0.5, len(A_data))
    for i in range(0, len(A_data), 100):
        alpha = alphas[i]
        a = A_data[i]
        ax[2].axvline(a, alpha=alpha, linestyle="--", color="black")
    ax[2].legend(loc="upper right")
    fig.suptitle("training-process", fontsize=15, y=0.95)
```

Output Results:

```
Step #1000: A = 6.72    Loss = 1.13

Step #2000: A = 3.93    Loss = 0.58

Step #3000: A = 2.12    Loss = 0.319

Step #4000: A = 1.63    Loss = 0.331

Step #5000: A = 1.58    Loss = 0.222

[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  2.
  0.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
Training:   Accuracy = 0.475    Shape = (80, 1)
Testing:    Accuracy = 0.5  Shape = (20, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your model doesn't do classification

You have a linear regression model, i.e., your output variable (model = tf.multiply(pH_x, A)) outputs for each input a single scalar value with an arbitrary range. That's generally what you'd have for a *prediction* model, one that needs to predict some numeric value, not for a classifier.

Afterwards, you treat it like it would contain a typical n-ary classifier output (e.g. by passing it sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) but it does not match the expectations of that function - in that case, the 'shape' of the model variable should be *multiple* values (e.g. 2 in your case) per input datapoint, each corresponding to some metric corresponding to the probability for each class; then often passed to a softmax function to normalize them.

Alternatively, you may want a binary classifier model that outputs a single value 0 or 1 depending on the class - however, in that case, you want something like the logistic function after the matrix multiplication; and that would need a different loss function, something like simple mean square difference, not sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits.

Currently the model as written seems like a mash of two different, incompatible tutorials.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Some of the differences are: (1) The shape of `pH_x` and `pH_y_hat` in the tutorial are `[1, None]` instead of `[None,1]` but I couldn't get that to work; (2) `model` is `tf.add(pH_x, A)` instead of `tf.multiply(pH_x, A)` which I thought was an error b/c I thought this was a regression with converted logits; (3) his prediction part uses `tf.squeeze(tf.round(tf.nn.nsigmoid(tf.add(pH_x, A))))` so I can try that but I thought the logits would be going through which is why I used the other function.  Thanks for the insight.  I will fix and then accept it in a few.